# How to sync Google+ Instant Upload with Google Drive?

Tags: sync, images, google-plus

I'm using Google+ Instant Upload to automatically sync all of the photos I take on my phone over a Wi-Fi connection. I also use Google Drive to backup my documents, music, pictures and videos folders.

### Is there a way to sync Google+ Instant Upload with Google Drive?

Ideally the way it would work is I would take photos with my phone, they would sync to my Google Drive "pictures" folder and then Google Drive on my pc would sync them into my photos library. Is this possible? Will it be added in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thread on Google Groups that covers this issue. By the answer provided by [AnaLikesLattes](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/zjydnDf972w/gC2YFesWmj4J), this is being considered and possible prepared by Google Staff since 5/1/12:

## [Android Instant Upload to Drive](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/zjydnDf972w)

> Hi all,
>
> Thanks for your input. We've heard many requests along these lines, and are definitely looking into potential solutions on our end.
>
> I will do my best to keep this forum updated once relevant features start to become available. In the meantime, please keep posting your requests about the Drive Android app! We're always excited to hear from our users.
>
> Cheers,
>   Ana

As far as I can tell, this is not yet implemented and a year has passed.

Since both applications are from Google and they alone can take the necessary steps to have this feature implemented properly, I would suggest to you and any interested person to visit the thread and leave the "feature-wish" there.

---

## App Suggestion

While it would be great to have a native solution for this problem, [Oliver Salzburg](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/11331/oliver-salzburg) commented on [my post at Google+](https://plus.google.com/112532098784425316005/posts/3DukxWqCwce) about this issue refering the app suggested bellow, that I've just now tested and is working beautifully sending all of my files to my desired destination on the Google Drive.

## [FolderSync Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en)

> FolderSync is a application that enables simple sync to cloud based storage to and from local folders on the device memory card. It currently support multiple SkyDrive, Dropbox, SugarSync, Ubuntu One, Box.net, LiveDrive, HiDrive, Google Docs, NetDocuments, Amazon S3, FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WebDAV or windows share (Samba/CIFS) accounts, and support for more platforms are planned.

[image: Folder Sync Lite - Main Menu] [image: Folder Sync Lite - Add Google Drive] [image: Folder Sync Lite - Folderpairs]

You don't need more than 5 minutes to complete the 3 basic steps:

1. Add your Google Drive account
2. Add a folderpair
3. Start the sync process

Answer (score 0):

I've just published an app for automatic photo upload to Google Drive with lots of convenient options.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mynextandroid.drivephotosync

[image]

It's free so give it a try!

Comment: Before this get's any more downvotes: Would you mind elaborating what makes your app special in contract to the build in photo/video sync feature e.g. the Google+ app?

Comment: It does not send your photos/videos to Google+ at all (some people prefer to stay out of G+). It aims to be like old Drive app sync feature.

Comment: So it doesn't send the photo's to Google+ but "just" to Google Drive? I see how some people may prefer that, but for me it seems to make little to no difference if I upload my personal photos to one or another USA-based cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Sweet Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sweesoft.sweethome), a free app, to upload photos and videos from my Android devices over Wi-Fi at home to my NAS Google Drive folder.  (This is fast 300mbit/s).  Then the Google Drive tool on my NAS (which has Windows OS) uploads the pictures and videos to Google Drive to be able to share and have an extra cloud backup. The Google+ app can be used to easily watch and browse through the pictures.

So I don't use the upload function in Google+, because I can't find an easy way to sync the photos locally after that and uploading right from the mobile device to internet is always slower than locally to the NAS.